# How to link to another path in React Native application from android service (or other activity, not MainActivity)

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have MainActivity in Android, where runs my RN application (as I see).
RN app has such route structure:

```
- Main window
-- First scene
-- Second scene
-- Other scene
```

Now I need to create android service and run my RN application, but not "Main window" but immediately the "Second scene".

How can I do this? What tools need to use for this?

Comment: You're looking for what's called "Deep Links", and it's too much to cover in a SO answer. Just read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) and [this](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e), it should at least give you the general idea.

Comment: OK, but if I don't have any extarnal links, and want to open in some cases "Second scene" from my MainActivity, how can I tell for RN app that in custom case I need open not Main window but Secont scene? In general, I want to run RN app from MainActivity in my own context

Comment: That's what a "Deep Link" is - it opens an app and immediatelly drills down to some custom page of it other than Main. External systems pretty much have no idea about your app's language, so they will use a URI of some description to access it, at which point your app has to understand what it's requested to do.

Comment: Thanks @M.Prokhorov, I found solution and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. As I don't need to handle external URL I don't need the Deep Linking. 
My problem was the context in which I want to open my React Native application. And context I must apply in Java, because I must handle different services. And I need to know, which service was start my MainActivity. In service I can put `extras` for Intent and then in Activity get those `extras`. But how to pass those `extras` to RN app? Main solution is `initialProps` that put to RN app when it started from Java.
I found solution with `initialProps` here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4504#issuecomment-250907062

Then I can take `initialProps` from `props` of the `RootComponent` in my RN app.